# Blazor: TelerikUpload component

Tags: c#, telerik, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use TelerikUpload component in my application. I am very new with the blazor and I am stuck with a problem where I don't want to use @SaveURl to upload my document, I am doing the document save functionality on my button click, so when I don't use the @Saveurl property in the TelerikUpload component it shows me the 'Uploading status' which I am not able to find a way to hide or make it work.

I just want to find a way where is just simply select the file and add it in the collection.

[image]

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What you see is expected, this type of upload is the goal of the component. For simple file selection, see the answer and my comment on it.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using the TelerikFileSelect component. This way you can implement your own posting logic.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the TelerikUpload control.  To the best of my understanding, it requires you to set the SaveURI parameter.

If you just want a control that can select files (but not do anything with them), you might want to check out Steve Sanderson's BlazorInputFile control:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/

https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile

Comment: Indeed, the TelerikUpload aims to provide async uploads to an endoint, which is the harder task. To get files to the Blazor code is simpler (through a package or a simplt input file) and you can Follow the implementation of a Telerik component for that here https://feedback.telerik.com/blazor/1460649-fileselect-component